# Question about what is the best method of adding GTM Event Tracking

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am "kinda new" to Google Tag Manager. Meaning I've created several tags, and manage several sites using it. However, I am curious if the process I have set up for Event tracking is considered a "best practice." Therefore, I am looking for ideas to improve it.

**Goal:** For any given website version release, I would like to assign all event tracking to a single Google Analytics Event tag.

All of the tutorials online have you entering an individual GA Event tag for each event you are tracking. This seems crazy to me, so I am hoping to avoid that by consolidating them as much as possible.

Comments?

**Precondition**
I am fortunate that I have access to my devs, and they are awesome at adding unique ids to everything I need to track. I am assuming ids are used to locate elements.

**Create a new Workspace unique to the elements being tracked**

- Create a new workspace in GTM describing the events I've been requested to add. I often get short, requests from our Management to add tracking to specific elements. So I add this info to the Workspace description.
- Use this workspace only for creating the events in this "release."

**Create variable for the Event's Action, Label, and/or Value**

- Create a new Lookup Table Variable.
- In the look up table, select Click ID as the input.
- Add the id the Devs assigned to the element we're tracking.
- Add the Action the you want assigned to the element.
- Repeat so you have a complete list of all the event's ids and their corresponding Action.
- Name the variable something that makes sense to you.
- Repeat for the Event's Label and/or Value.

**Create a Trigger for each of the elements being tracked**

- Go to the Triggers section and create a new Click Trigger.
- Set it up so it is only triggered when the element's ClickID is clicked.
- Save the trigger with a name that makes sense to you.
- Repeat for each of the elements being tracked.

**Create a GA Event Tag unique to this "Release" and add Triggers**

- Add a new GA tag with a predefined name that describes what I am tracking.
- Select Events instead of pageviews
- Enter the Category y'all want for the Event
- Select the variables created for the Event's Action, Label, and/or value.
- Add all of the triggers to the tag.

Preview the tag. If it's right, then publish the release and merge back with the main workspace.

Repeat at the next release whenever I need to add more event tracking.

---